# Selenium: Loop trough links on webpage and switch to the next page after collecting the data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, d

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

elemental_list = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for page in range(1, 21):
    page_url = "https://www.fastexpert.com/top-real-estate-agents/florida/?page=" + str(page)
    driver.get(page_url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.TOP25AGENTSE10.RTAGENTCOLUMN div.TOPREPT_RRT")))
    for agent in range(1,25):
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h3").click() #Finding the link on the page
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h1") #finding the name on the personal page
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "my_map_adress") #finding the location on the personal page

    agents = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml').find('section', {'class': 'TOP25AGENTSE10 RTAGENTCOLUMN'}).find_all('div', {'class': 'TOPREPT_RRT'})

    for agent in agents:
        elemental_list.append((agent.find('h1').text.strip(), agent.find({'id': 'my_map_adress'}).text.strip())) if agent.find({'class': 'my_map_adress'}) else elemental_list.append((agent.find('h1').text, ''))

for element in elemental_list:
    print(element)

driver.quit()
```

I try to scrap data from that website. The goal is to click the links and scrap the name and the address. After clicking all 25 links on page 1, it should loop through all 20 pages and do the same. I think my logic is right, but I'm kinda stuck. What do I not see what breaks my code?

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="my_map_adress"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.199); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00AAA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x00A3C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00945358]
    (No symbol) [0x009709A5]
    (No symbol) [0x00970B3B]
    (No symbol) [0x0099E232]
    (No symbol) [0x0098A784]
    (No symbol) [0x0099C922]
    (No symbol) [0x0098A536]
    (No symbol) [0x009682DC]
    (No symbol) [0x009693DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D0AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D4A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D4456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B351E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00A45F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00A42328]
    (No symbol) [0x00A4240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00A34FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x770000C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777D7B4E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777D7B1E+238]
```

Comment: Maybe you have misspel in word 'adress' try 'address'

Comment: How many links is it able to actually click? Does it click only the first one then crash or is it able to get through the first page before getting stuck?

Comment: as the error clearly says, there are no such `id` or `class` with the value `my_map_adress` on the webpage and that's why It throws `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: It just opens the page and then crashes. It does not open any links. I think the error occurs in the agents variable but I'm not sure what's wrong or how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has semantic issues in multiple places.

```
for agent in range(1,25):
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h3").click()
```

At these lines, you're trying to click on the first person's profile, 25 times, which in turn has multiple issues,

- `h3` tag isn't clickable
- even if it was clickable, you're trying to go to the first person's profile 25 times
- after the first click the page would've changed, which would've rendered other clicks or elements useless, raising another set of errors.

Your code for fetching details is also outside this loop, so it'd have taken the details from the last opened page only.

Issues aside, I noticed that the website is static, so you need not use selenium unless there's some constraint, so I rewrote the code in `requests`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

elemental_list = []
headers = {
    'Host': 'www.fastexpert.com'
}

for page in range(1, 21):
    page_url = f"https://www.fastexpert.com/top-real-estate-agents/florida/?page={page}"
    print(page_url)

    page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page_url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')
    
    agents = page.find_all('a', {'class': 'profileLink', 'href':re.compile('\/agents\/')})

    
    for agent in agents:
        agent_url = agent.get('href')
        print(agent_url)
        agent_page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(agent_url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')

        if agent_page.find('h1') and (agent_page.find('h1').text.strip() != 'Not Found'):
            elemental_list.append((agent_page.find('h1').text.strip(), agent_page.find('address', {'id': 'my_map_adress'}).text.strip())) if agent_page.find('address', {'id': 'my_map_adress'}) else elemental_list.append((agent_page.find('h1').text, ''))
            print(elemental_list[-1])
```

At the line `page.find_all('a', {'class': 'profileLink', 'href':re.compile('\/agents\/')})` I am fetching all the matching anchors having the given class and matching the given `href` pattern.

This code outputs:

```
('DeWayne Carpenter', '605 Lincoln Rd #7th Floor, Miami, FL, 33139')
('Kirk Kessel', '719 Pine Tree, Satellite Beach, FL, 32937')
('Chris Creegan', '439 Lake Howell Rd, Maitland, FL, 32751')
('Jeff Tricoli Team', '2005 Vista Parkway Suite 100, West Palm Beach, FL, 33411')
('Jeffrey Borham', '2945 Alt 19 N #Ste A, Palm Harbor, FL, 34683')
('Brenda Wade', '1709 Bloomingdale Ave, Valrico, FL, 33596')
('Sandy Blanton', '1225 W. Gregory St., Pensacola, FL, 32502')
('Welch Team', '301 Kingsley Lake Drive, Saint Augustine, FL, 32092')
('Liz Piedra', '11534 Spring Hill Dr., Spring Hill, FL, 34609')
('Mike Gagliardi', '5889 S. Williamson Blvd, Suite 1401, Port Orange, FL, 32128')
('David & Toni Zarghami', '3355 Clark Rd, Suite 103 #Suite 308, Sarasota, FL, 34232')
('Jeffrey G. Funk', '422 Main Street, Windermere, FL, 34786')
('Sarah and Tim Caudill', '223 N Causeway, New Smyrna Beach, FL, 32169')
('Kevin Bartlett', '21301 S Tamiami trail suite 340, Estero, FL,')
('Christian Bennett', '11541 Trinity Blvd., Trinity, FL, 34655')
('Ben Laube', '422 Main StreetÂ\xa0|Â\xa0Suite 1, Windermere, FL, 34786')
('Nichole Roberts', '1705 E Fort King St , Ocala, FL, 34471')
('Sandra Rathe', '1625 N Commerce Pkwy Unit 100, Weston, FL, 33326')
('Cynthia Fazzini', '4175 Woodlands Pkwy, Palm Harbor, FL, 34684')
('Jayson Burtch', '3251 Tamiami trail, Port Charlotte, FL, 33952')
('Lisa Carroll', '2440 Land O lakes Blvd, Land O Lakes, FL, 34639')
('Jennifer Fieo', '2020 W Brandon Blvd #Ste 145, Brandon, FL, 33510')
('Barrett Spray', '59 Alafaya Woods Blvd, Oviedo, FL, 32765')
('JoAnn and Tom Jacobs', '3303 Thomasville Road #Suite 201, Tallahassee, FL, 32308')
('Jennifer Wemert', '650 N. Alafaya Trail, Suite 105, Orlando, FL, 32828')
```

You can change the number of pages in the loop definition.

Comment: If I increase the loop count to 21 so it loops trough alle the pages I get this error: File "C:\Users\David\PycharmProjects\FastExperts 2\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    'address', {'id': 'my_map_adress'}) else elemental_list.append((agent_page.find('h1').text, ''))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @DaveMier88, Agent #74 *Kelly Fischer* has an invalid URL, updated the code to skip this kind of elements.

Comment: Should I add the except Exception: return? Because it says: return outside of function. That's what I thought of: for page in range(1, 20):
    `page_url = f"https://www.fastexpert.com/top-real-estate-agents/florida/?page={page}"
    try:
        page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page_url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')
        page.raise_for_status()
    except Exception:
        return`

Comment: change return to `pass`, it'd work

Comment: Have you checked my updated code though? I haven't got any error with it.

Comment: I overread that you edited it xD But pass will work too right?

Comment: Yes, `pass` would also work, though I'd recommended not to overuse it, as you won't be able to track any other issues as well.